# VW T2 Headlining Replacement

Tags: vw, interior

I'm about to launch upon replacing the headliner of my 1976 VW T2 Microbus.

Whilst looking for hints on how to do it I have seen a couple of blogs that say it is only possible if all the windows are removed from the bus first.  is this really so?  It seems an awfully complicated way of doing things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds quite likely - I can't picture the inside of a T2 at the moment, but you'll probably find the headlining goes behind the inside of the window rubbers - which looks neater and is easier for replacing windows - just a lot harder for replacing headliners!

In fact most cars usually have the window rubbers on fixed windows covering the edges of the interior trim - side panels as well.

Is the liner damaged? I've seen faded but undamaged ones rejuvenated quite well by painting them - but obviously that's no good if it's torn...

Comment: The headlining does tuck behind the window rubbers.  But so does the upholstery below the windows and I replaced that without taking the windows out, just pushing the new vinyl under the the rubber.  Painting is something I hadn't thought of.  There are a couple of minor tears in the headliner.

Comment: I suspect that the difference there is that the headlining needs to be stretched to create it's shape, whereas the other trim is probably self-supporting - so you'll need access to edges of the headliner to attach it...